# web page Firefox plugin or extension

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, browser-extension

I'm building a small web app that should run in the background while the user browse the web,
a dynamically added Iframe isn't an option since I can't reload it anytime the user refresh or switch page.
while on Google Chrome this is pretty easy to accomplish, I can't find anywhere an example or documentation on how to implement that on Firefox

I guess what I'm really after is a method to open a non depended totally chrome-less frame (which will run my web app and stays there even if the users switch or refresh pages)

Any Ideas?

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? Any code that you will load in an overlay for `browser.xul` will run as long as the window is open.

Answer (score 0):

The best way would be to add a listener for when the browser changes the url and then communicate with ajax the data you want.

Answer (score 0):

The closest thing that matches your description is hiddenWindow, which is an undocumented and unsupported way to have random webby content in a window not displayed anywhere in UI.

If you said what exactly you're trying to do, you'd get more useful answers.